# MATLAB PTB3 - Handle Blinking error display at the experiment beginning

Tags: matlab, psychtoolbox

There is a flashing red screen at the beginning of the experiment I'm running via Matlab Psyctoolbox3.
It looks like this:

[image]

I know that this is a common issue caused by the `Screen('OpenWindow');` command.
How can I resolve the alert reason, or at least to disable this visual cue?
I have used `Screen('Preference', 'SkipSyncTests', 1);` already.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to resolve the alert reason,
but to disable the alert screen display use:

```
Screen('Preference','VisualDebugLevel', 0);
```

under:

```
Screen('Preference', 'SkipSyncTests', 1);
```